# Clone and insert node within createElement()

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm working on a bit of code that changes image tags to support lazy loading, and I want to insert a `<noscript>` tag containing the original image node before each image.

I'm getting stuck on the part where I insert a duplicate of the image node inside of the `<noscript>` tag. I'm new to `DomDocument`, so I'm sure I must be doing something wrong. How can I clone the image tag and insert it in to the new `<noscript>` element I'm creating?

```
function lazy_load_images($content) {
    if ($content) {
        $DOM = new DOMDocument();
        $DOM->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

        $images = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("img");

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $existing_src    = $image->getAttribute("src");
            $existing_srcset = $image->getAttribute("srcset");

            // add noscript before images (here's where the hang-up is)
            $DOM->documentElement->insertBefore($DOM->createElement("noscript", $image->cloneNode(false)), $image->nextSibling);

            // change src to data-normal
            if ($existing_src) {
                $image->removeAttribute("src");
                $image->setAttribute("data-normal", $existing_src);
            }

            // change srcset to data-srcset
            if ($existing_srcset) {
                $image->removeAttribute("srcset");
                $image->setAttribute("data-srcset", $existing_srcset);
            }

            // add _js class
            $image->setAttribute("class", "_js {$image->getAttribute("class")}");
        }

        return $DOM->saveHTML();
    }
}
```

Comment: `createElement` only has the name and value(a string) as parameters.  If you want to put a node underneath it - create the node and `appendChild` the cloned node to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment.  `createElement` has parameters of a string for the names and values, so create the `<noscript>` node and the append the cloned node to that and then insert it.

```
$noscript = $DOM->createElement("noscript");
$noscript->appendChild($image->cloneNode());
$image->parentNode->insertBefore($noscript, $image->nextSibling);
```

I've noticed that if you use `$images = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("img");` that the loop seems to never end.  If you use `$images = $xp->query('//img');` instead, it seems to work.

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($DOM);

$images = $xp->query('//img');
```

Comment: This is causing some sort of memory leak or something; the page keeps loading and my servers CPU goes up to 100%. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I just tried this with `$noscript->appendChild($noscript->cloneNode(false));`, and that works fine, so there must be something weird with cloning the image node... EDIT: It appears to be an issue with anything that I'm loading in with the `$DOM-loadHTML`; tried with paragraph tags, same thing, infinite loading.

Comment: Have you checked the html it generates?  Do a view source and check if you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't get far enough to see the output.

Comment: `echo $DOM->saveXML($image->cloneNode())` outputs valid HTML just fine, so this really confusing.

Comment: I was going to suggest changing the false, when your copying a node - even the attributes are sub-nodes.

Comment: Try echo'ing `$DOM->saveXML($noscript)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158988/discussion-between-jacobthedev-and-nigel-ren).

Comment: The loop seems to be the problem, changing the line listing the nodes to `$images = $xp->query('//img');` seems to work (in my own test)